# Relational database Design- Relationship problem

Tags: database, database-design, one-to-many, relational-database

I need to create database tables to store memo. in the "To" clause user may select individual employee or group of employees (Different groups are already available in database having many to many relationship with employee). i am wondering what should be structure of tables.
For simple memo where there are no groups i will have "MemoMasters" and "Memodetails" with memodetail having EmployeeID as foreign key. how could i embed groups in this structure

Regards

Comment: I need to store the acknowledgment information of each employee also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you approach it as a Relational modelling task, I don't see the complexity.  Assuming you want a pure Relational solution, try this [**Memo Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Tassadaque%20Memo.pdf).  If you are unfamiliar with the Standard for modelling Relational databases, the [**IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) may be helpful.

1. It uses an ordinary Supertype-Subtype Structure.

   - In this case it is Exclusive: the MemoAddress ie *either* and an EmployeeAddress *or* a GroupAddress.
   - Exclusive Subtypes need a Discriminator in the Supertype: I have used a boolean `IsEmployee`, a CHAR code or similar is also common.
2. This is pure 5NF; no Update Anomalies; full Declarative Referential Integrity.
3. Ack is in the right place (I've used a DateTime, but boolean is fine as well).
4. The projection to populate Supertype-Subtype structure might look ugly, though, if you are not used to it; just ask if you need help.
5. Do not treat "simple memos with one employee" differently, you will run into problems, duplicated code, etc.
6. A separate issue is, you may need the `EmployeeId` of the `Employee` who **wrote** the `Memo`, which is a different thing, and for that you do need an FK for `Employee` in `Memo`.

Comment: this gives me a another way to see the problem. Although i implemented a little denormalized solution :( but i will definitely look into it again. i have another problem related to database could you please elaborate on this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409003/storing-weekly-targets-in-database

Answer (score 0):

In this structure you could not.

This is a [many to many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship, model it as such.

EDIT (reviewing the scenario):
The above requirements are not enough to determine the 'exact solution'

At the risk of overly simplifying, you should:

1) check if you can stick the new information into any existing tables/entities
2) if not, then check if adding attributes/columns to any of the existing tables/entties
3) if not, then add a new table

The decisions are never clearly cut and you **should** consider several scenarios and their consequences. You should also periodically review your model as it envolves to look for opportunities to normalize it as it will greatly impact overall functionality of your system.

So, for example, as you state that you already have a many to many table for groups the main question now is weather to reuse that table or create a new one.

This depends on the other attributes that are in this table. Maybe for your business model/use case it makes sense, maybe it does not.

Maybe you need to model a table called as "MemoRecipients" which will store info on recipients (delivery, acknowledgement, etc...). Then you should ask yourself do you need the times for all these statuses, etc, etc...

Only you can determine what is a proper design decision for your problem space.

Comment: i know it is many to many relationship but please review the scenario it is little bit complex

Comment: @Tassadaque, reviewed and updated. Unfortunately the answer can only be in form of suggestions and advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you need an inheritance heirarchy to achieve what you describe. Consider the diagram below:

[image: Database Inheritance.]

In this diagram you create a parent table (I call it Poster) and the employee and group tables are children. You have to give the employee table and the group table the same primary key, that is, there are one to one links from group to poster and employee to poster.

This way, the poster_id field of memo is pointing to the super class. You can perform a join between poster, group and employee to determine whether you are refering to an employee or a group.

I left out the relationship between employee and group from the diagram as you said you have that already.

Note that this is just an illustration of what is possible, you solution may vary.

Comment: Thanks for your good reply but there seems one problem with this approach. your proposed approach works fine if both group and employee deos not have direct relationship but employee and group have many to many relationship. As i mentioned earlier i need to store the ack info for each employee either he belong to group or not. how the ack will be handled in above case. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Since the relationship between employee and group is a many to many, then you will create a relation to represent this. Let us call it employee_group. That will take care of your many to many. That still works with above design. Can you explain the acknowledgement a bit more?

Comment: Ack means every employee that belongs to group or not has to acknowledge that he has received the memo. it is a boolean field. This field is part of memo that is linked to poster in your proposed case. So ack will be stored for group in above figure